# How to get data from db and set to nested list<object>

Tags: class, view, nested

I have a nested `list<object>`:

```
public class ItemsOfQuestions { 
    public string item_title { get; set; } 
    public Byte item_type { get; set; } 
    public string item_image { get; set; } 
    public Int16 item_grade { get; set;}
} 
public class Questins_With_Items { 
    public string question_title { get; set; } 
    public List<ItemsOfQuestions> list_items { get; set; } 
}
```

I get data from db and set to list,
but I get this error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(graph1.ViewModels.ItemsOfQuestions)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Can anybody help?

Comment: my list<object> is:  public class ItemsOfQuestions
    {
        public string item_title { get; set; }
        public Byte item_type { get; set; }
        public string item_image { get; set; }
        public Int16 item_grade { get; set;}
    }
    public class Questins_With_Items
    {
        
        public string question_title { get; set; }
        public List<ItemsOfQuestions> list_items { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Please edit your question to include both your source (almost unreadable in your comment) and show more information about your DB query. We aren't in a position to read your mind or your computer's mind.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what language and system you are using.